# VB.NET - Downloading File From Webpage

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to download the latest Kodi ARM build for Android from `http://Kodi.tv/download` and save it to a pre-existing folder on my computer. I just want to click a button and it will download that file to where it needs to be. The current code that I am using is opening up an IE browser and giving the dialogue;

> Open, Save, Save As..

Here is the current code that I am using:

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        If Element.OuterHtml.Contains("ARM") Then
            Element.InvokeMember("click")
           End If
    Next
```

This is grabbing the button off of the Webbrowser that I have on the form and clicking it. I also can not use a static link as I want to get the latest updates [link changes].

How can I download the item I need from the web page to a predesignated folder with no dialogues?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i download the item i need from the webpage to a predesignated folder with no dialogues.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code online and it works great so i thought i would share it!

```
 Dim Address As String = String.Empty
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Dim fileReader As New WebClient()
        Address = " *Link* "
        filename = " *Filename of what you want to save as* "
        If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(" *Download Location* " + filename)) Then
            fileReader.DownloadFile(Address, " *Download Location* " + filename)
        End If
    Catch ex As HttpListenerException
        Console.WriteLine("Error accessing " + Address + " - " + ex.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error accessing " + Address + " - " + ex.Message)
    End Try
    MsgBox("Done")
End Sub
```

**Found here: [Here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/download-files-over-the-web-with-nets-webclient-class/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the .NET `WebClient` class.  It has very convenient methods like `DownloadFile`, which take a URL to download, and a location to save.

Because the URL is constantly changing, you will likely need to still use the web browser to determine what the current URL is.  Once you have this, you can dispose of your web browser and pass the URL to `DownloadFile`.  There's even events to monitor download progress and completion, `DownloadProgressChanged` and `DownloadFileCompleted`. If you intend on using these, ensure that you use the async version, `DownloadFileAsync`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have looked into the web client and this does make everything a lot easier! Thanks! But where i am stuck is getting the URL address from the webpages button.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to find just that URL, but there is likely a way to do it using the WebBrowser class alone.