# Download file from Sharepoint in blank and 0KB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sharepoint

I am developing a small application that connects to a sharepoint to be able to download some files from a document folder.

The detail is that when I download the file, it downloads it empty and with 0KB in the file size and when I try to open the file, send a message that say is damaged or corrupted.

This is the code developed.

```
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
    Imports System.IO        
    Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
    Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
    Imports System.Security
    Imports System.Net
    
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
         Dim siteUrl As String = "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/TRAINING/"
         Dim authManager = New OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager()
         Dim ctx As ClientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl)
         Dim web As Web = ctx.Web
         ctx.Load(web, Function(w) w.Title)
         ctx.ExecuteQuery()
         Console.WriteLine("You have connected to {0} site, with Multi Factor Authentication enabled!!", web.Title)
         
         DeleteFilesInsideFolder("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test")

         rPath = "https://example.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/TRAINING/Data/Example.xlsx"
         destination = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test\Example.xlsx"

         Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(rPath, destination)
         Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred:" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
         End Try
        
    End Sub


    Sub DeleteFilesInsideFolder(ByVal target_folder_path As String)

         For Each file_path As String In Directory.GetFiles(target_folder_path)
              Try
                  My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(file_path)
              Catch ex As Exception
                  MessageBox.Show("An error occurred:" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
              End Try
         Next

    End Sub
```

Please, could you help me to know why?, any idea?

Regards.

Comment: Add an @ before all of your path from disk?  `@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test\Example.xlsx"`

Comment: @高鵬翔, thank you for your answer, but when I add @ before of the path, send **"Expression expected"** and cant continue. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, it's my fault, it use on C# not vb.net, maybe you could try to change `https` to `http`? It's hard to find the error without your environment.> <"

Comment: Any error exception?

Comment: @高鵬翔, same result if change `https` to `http`. Any other idea? :(

Comment: use `http` and delete the local file try again:? It seems can't overwrite when file exist in default?

Comment: @高鵬翔, yes I use `DeleteFilesInsideFolder("C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test")` to delete all files in the path, but is the same result and using `http`.

Comment: No, Maybe `DeleteFilesInsideFolder` didn't have `async await` so that I guess it create in the same time...   So I said you may try delete by your hand to try if it could download.

Comment: @高鵬翔, no, same result :(

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43454780/13107433) could help.

Comment: @高鵬翔, try whit the link, but send an error `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`. I know that this is because for the authentication, but the query to access its ok.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857162/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-vb-net)

Comment: @高鵬翔, same result, blank file and 0KB size. :(

Comment: Maybe try to use `WebClient` [instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776942/vb-net-downloading-file-from-webpage)